# How to check if the parameter exist in python

Tags: python, linux

I would like to create a simple python script that will take a parameter from the console, and it will display this parameter. If there will be no parameter then I would like to display error message, but custom message not something like IndexError: list index out of range

Something like this:

```
if isset(sys.argv[1]):
    print sys.argv[1];
else:
    print "No parameter has been included"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    print(sys.argv[1])
else:
    print("No parameter has been included")
```

For more complex command line interfaces there is the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module
in Python's standard library - but for simple projects taking just a couple parameters directly checking `sys.argv` is alright.

**update** as of 2019, the recomendation is to use the external library "[click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/)", as it provides very "Pythonic" ways of including complex documents in a way they are easily documented.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the lenght

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    ...
```

Or the try/except

```
try:
    sys.argv[1]
except IndexError as ie:
    print("Exception : {0}".format(ie))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

try:
    print sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print "No parameter has been included"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
print sys.argv[0]   # will print your file name
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print sys.argv[1];
else:
    print "No parameter has been included"
```

OR

```
import sys
try:
   print sys.argv[1]
except IndexError, e:
   print "No parameter has been included"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you can also use `getopt` which provides you a way of predefining the options that are acceptable using the unix `getopt` conventions.

```
import sys
import getopt
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hvxrc:s:", ["help", "config=", "section="])
except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print ("Option error:", str(err))
    opts=[]
for op , val in opts:
    print ("option",op,"Argument",val)
if not opts:
    print ("No parameter supplied")
```

In the above if an incorrect parameter is supplied all of the options are scrapped.
Examples of use would be:

```
python myprog.py -h
python myprog.py --help
python myprog.py -c123
python myprog.py --config=123
```

https://pymotw.com/2/getopt/
http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_getopt.htm

Answer (score 0):

without exception model using if else short hand, in single line we can read args

```
    args = sys.argv
    env = args[1:] and args[1] or None
    username = args[2:] and args[2] or None
    password = args[3:] and args[3] or None
```